# Translate screen position to image pixel coordinate with android

Tags: android, imageview, xamarin.android

I have a ImageView they use a TouchListener with a GestureDetector to handle a SingleTap event, I'm able to get the touch (x,y) position.

Now, I would like to get the pixel coordinates of the touch position. I have play without success with the ImageView matrix..

Answer (score 0):

Getting color from pixcel using bitmap like this:

```
ImageView imageView =((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

Comment: at the end it doesn't work as expected... My image have 16 colors

Comment: It gives the colour pixcel which you touch the image

Comment: What you expected from here?

Comment: but when the area of the pixel who is touched  have uniform color it's not accurate?

Comment: Then you have to gat the alpha color of the pixcel. Then you may got accurate color. Try this way..